# «Por la mañana» frente a «en la mañana»

Tags: diferencias-regionales, preposiciones, tiempo, ecuador

Mientras voy calificando algunos escritos de mis alumnos, he notado que a pesar de lo que les digo en clase, escriben cosas como «Me ducho en la mañana» o «salgo en la noche», frases en las cuales usaría exclusivamente «por» para referirme al período del día.

Los libros de texto, tanto como mi experiencia, confirman que el uso normal es «por».  No obstante, sí que he escuchado el uso de «en» de un colega de Ecuador que me lo ha dicho un par de veces.

¿Es normal y corriente decir cosas como «Lo haré en la mañana» o «Vuelvo de clase en la tarde»?  Y si es regional, ¿cómo se escucha cada forma en las zonas que usan la otra palabra?  Es decir, ¿suena raro, normal, dialectal?

Comment: También podríamos añadir "a la mañana". ¿O tiene otras connotaciones?

Comment: He encontrado esto que puede aclarar un poco el tema: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg#6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si trato de analizarlo siempre he dicho "en la mañana/tarde/noche". Comparándolo con "por la mañana" no sabría decirte diferencia alguna, suenan exactamente igual para mí. La única diferencia que encuentro es que "por la mañana" suena un poco a textos escritos para mí y también describe a algo que va a suceder durante la mañana:

> Mañana por la mañana tengo que hacer muchas cosas

y la otra forma es más específica a un momento en especial pero la diferencia es ínfima. Aún así lo más común en México sería "en la mañana" pero si alguien dijera "por la mañana" no habría nada de extraño.  Sé que he dicho "por la mañana" pero lo que siempre acostumbro a decir/escuchar es "en la mañana".

Comment: Curioso.  Para mí, algo como «Salgo en la noche» tiene la noche no como un período de tiempo sino un lugar/cosa (es decir, «me voy despareciendo en la oscuridad nocturna»).  ¿Seríate intercamable «mañana en la mañana tengo que hacer algo» con lo que tienes en tu respuesta?

Comment: Me llama la atención la manera en la que entiendes "Salgo en la noche", nunca se me habría ocurrido pensarlo así. Y sí, para mi no sólo es completamente intercambiable "mañana en la mañana tengo que hacer algo" sino que sería lo que diría de manera cotidiana.

Comment: Le di un toque poético, pero sí para mí sería como «ir por la noche» (viajar entre anochecer y medianoche/amanecer) e «ir en la noche» (viajar en la oscuridad causada por estas horas).  De todas formas, si son tan intercambiables, dejaré de corregírselo a los alumnos.

Answer (score 2):

En Argentina, "por la mañana" es la forma más común de decirlo.
La otra variante es "durante la mañana". No es común escuchar que alguien diga "en la mañana/tarde/noche". A mi entender, el uso de "por" y "durante" da alguna especie de continuidad de lo que se tenga que hacer. El uso de "en" me parecería más relacionado con algo puntual que ya ocurrió o va a ocurrir. Por ejemplo, en un programa de radio es común escuchar cosas como:

"En la mañana de hoy vamos a tener" o "en la mañana de hoy tuvimos"

No veo una gran diferencia, quizás la frecuencia del uso es más regional.

Como sugiere el comentario,
"A la mañana" también es común. Por ejemplo, "Mañana a la mañana voy a salir a correr" o "cuando vas a lavar los platos? Hoy a la noche".

Comment: Según mi experiencia, lo más común en Argentina es "A la mañana/tarde/noche".

Comment: Es cierto, OP pide diferencia entre dos opciones, por eso mi respuesta. Aún así agregué el comentario

Answer (score 2):

Aunque en las frases de la pregunta no se nota la diferencia, las preposiciones *en* y *por* tienen un significado bien diferente cuando se refieren al tiempo.

**En** se refiere a un momento puntual.

**Por** se refiere a un tiempo aproximado.

La diferencia se ve más clara en estas otras oraciones:

> Los problemas llegaron **por** Septiembre.
>
> Los problemas llegaron **en** Septiembre.

*Por Septiembre* significa *más o menos en Septiembre*, o cerca de esa fecha. En este caso también se usa la preposición **hacia**.

Answer (score 1):

En Chile decimos 'en la mañana'. La verdad es que nunca lo noté hasta ahora que estoy en el extranjero enseñando español y me dijeron que lo que yo decía estaba 'incorrecto'...

Answer (score 1):

En España se dice sin duda alguna 'por la mañana/tarde/noche'. Diría que la construcción 'en la mañana/tarde/noche' es usada por hablantes hispanoamericanos, aunque desconozco si es generalizado o solo en algunas zonas. En Perú, por ejemplo, sí se usa.

Answer (score 0):

En la mañana o por la mañana, son ambas formas correctas y sinónimas, no es una más correcta que la otra, implican momentos del día, tarde o noche sin más precisión. Cabe señalar que igualmente ni una ni la otra es representativa de una sola región, ya que en Sudamérica y Centroamérica se emplean ambas variantes.

El uso de *en* la mañana hace referencia al período del día en sí (en la mañana, tarde o noche), sin ninguna precisión mientras que *por* la mañana hace referencia a "en algún momento" de la mañana, también sin ninguna precisión, siempre que solo se relacione con los momentos del día.

No confundir con la narrativa, que marcará preferencia por una u otra forma según la abundancia de información, véase "En la mañana del 12 de octubre, Cristóbal Colón..." o "por la mañana me pasaré". La preposición de tiempo *en* marcará una ligera diferencia ya que incide en una fecha particular o por un acontecimiento = en la mañana del accidente; y *por* indicará "a lo largo de/cercano a/hacia" = las nevadas suelen ser por enero.

Por lo tanto, si solo se refiere a las partes del día sin más, tanto en la mañana como por la mañana son formas correctas ya que ambas implican imprecisión.

Decir que solo "por la mañana" es la forma correcta, es incorrecto.

Answer (score 0):

Soy hablante nativo y he vivido en Cuba y España. Y solo me he enterado por casualidad que en algunas zonas de la hispanosfera dicen “en la mañana” con este post. Nunca lo había escuchado antes. La primera vez que lo oí (y lo que me trajo aquí) fue un test de español de Duolingo que me puse a hacer por curiosidad para compararlo con otros idiomas que estoy aprendiendo. Cuando lo vi pensé que era una mala traducción literal del inglés “in the morning”. Yo siempre he visto «por la mañana» para hablar de la vida cotidiana. Solo he visto «en la mañana» utilizado en contextos como «en la mañana del día 10 de diciembre del año 1560, la expedición...». Así que «en la mañana» me suena incorrecto. *No digo que lo sea.* Simplemente, que al no haberlo visto nunca antes, intuitivamente me provoca esa sensación.

Comment: Bienvenido al stack. Gracias por la contribución, aunque creo que es más un comentario sobre tu experiencia personal que una respuesta que explique la diferencia entre ambas. Te recomiendo visitar [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor el funcionamiento del stack. Espero seguir viendo contribuciones tuyas por aquí.

Comment: @Diego Las preguntas eran 

`¿Es normal y corriente decir cosas como «Lo haré en la mañana» o «Vuelvo de clase en la tarde»? Y si es regional, ¿cómo se escucha cada forma en las zonas que usan la otra palabra? Es decir, ¿suena raro, normal, dialectal?`

¿Cómo se responde a preguntas así sin ser anecdótico? Está preguntando sobre el uso de una expresión, cómo suena, y dónde se usa. Mi respuesta es anecdótica, como buena parte de las otras respuestas, porque una pregunta de este tipo demanda respuestas de este tipo.