# Use of "Por" for location of time of the day?

Tags: gramática

I had a question if this was the best way to describe the English sentence

> Rosquillas and Coffee in the morning is delicious.

In Spanish would I use ***por*** for the description of the time of day?

> Rosquillas y café por la mañana es delicioso.

Is this alright to use, or is there a better way to describe **'in the morning'**?

Thanks

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10420/por-la-ma%C3%B1ana-frente-a-en-la-ma%C3%B1ana

Comment: The correct traslation (and if you want to consder in that way) of the sentence _in the morning_ is **en la mañana**, it may be also a _informal_ or a _regional_ way of say the same sentence. You should check the similar question linked by @Rodrigo in his comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Por` is the preposition used to refer to a general part of the day

> Por la mañana, por la tarde

It can be used with other nouns that determine time

> Por Navidad. Por agosto.

The preposition `en` can be used to form *locuciones temporales*

> Denota en qué lugar, **tiempo** o modo se realiza lo expresado por el verbo a que se refiere

- with the name of months: *En agosto*.
- names of seasons: *En primavera*.
- with years: *En 1984*.
- certain nouns: *Los Reyes Magos vienen en Navidad*.

The preposition `a` can be used to refer to hours of the day

> a las diez de la mañana  (or de 10am a 7pm)

It seems that most Spaniards would say "**por** la mañana" and some Latin Americans accept "**en** la mañana". There are even some regionalisms that would accept the use of `a`

> Nos vemos **a** la tarde

But I don't think I have ever heard this with "mañana" ("a la mañana") and means something closer to "next evening" than "every evening".

My suggestion would be to user `por` to describe a time frame of the day by name.

Comment: I've only ever heard *a la mañana* in a sequence like *Y a la mañana siguiente, acaeció algo* to mean, basically, *al amanecer, acaeció algo* where the concern isn't that it took place in the morning, but upon the arrival of the morning.

Comment: @guifa, I don't really think that I have ever heard of it to refer to recurrent actions. Almost always conveys "next" (nos vemos a la tarde--> Nos vemos luego). And I agree that is almost followed by "siguiente" (I also just found [this page](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/A%20la%20ma%C3%B1ana-Por%20la%20ma%C3%B1ana.htm) researching it a little bit more). Also, notice that is a regionalism.

Comment: I wouldn't use it for recurrent either. Probably should have said "arrival of the following morning" haha

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's correct.

In Spain we say it like that, in Latin America they might say *en la mañana*, which is also fine if you speak that variant of Spanish.

---

One correction:

> Rosquilla(s) y café por la mañana **son deliciosos**.

Since the subject is plural (*rosquilla(s) y café*, more than 1 element), the adjective has to be plural, too. In English sounds fine, because *rosquillas and coffee* forms a unit and you can use *is*, but Spanish doesn't work that way in this regard.

Also, to sound more natural, I'd add some *determinants*:

> **Unas** rosquillas y **un** café por la mañana son deliciosos.

Comment: Does `un café` equate to `coffee` or `a coffee`?  Because I would read `coffee` in the OP's question not necessarily being limited to one coffee.

Comment: @PeterM subjects almost always need determinantss, but because these are in coordination, you could leave out the un.  Another alternative would be "algo de café". If it were just coffee, you could just use "el café"